# Why do we use z-score proportions when we can easily calculate the exact proportion?

Tags: proportion, z-score

What's the purpose of z-score proportions when I can easily find the exactly proportion by counting how many measurements there are in range(x,y) and divide by sample size?

Comment: Your question lacks enough context to understand it. If you're calculating a proportion of a *sample* within a certain interval, why would you do it any other way than by counting?

Comment: I encountered this question asked to use zscore proportion to calculate the proportion of values less than xyz. With zscore proportion I get about 2%, whereas the real data gives 6%, I think the difference will probably be bigger if the sample size is smaller, or the distribution is slightly skewed, or the distribution is more slimmer/wider than a perfectly normal distribution. 
It's not a complicated process to calculate the proportion of values in a range by counting how many values lie in that range. So what's the purpose of z-score proportions? Does it has other important applications?

Comment: It's possible you have misunderstood what it asked or it's possible the question doesn't make sense (or indeed, perhaps some other issue exists). Without seeing the original question you were looking at, it's impossible to tell which it might be. [One possibility is that it may be asking about an estimate of the population proportion rather than the sample proportion; in that context there is a good question to ask about whether the sample proportion is a better way to estimate the population proportion than one based on assuming a normal distribution.]